# Simple graph of nodes and links without using force layout

Tags: javascript, d3.js

How can I make a basic connected graph (two nodes and a link connecting them for example) that doesn't use a `force()` layout?  I just want to be able to drag a node and have the link adjust to stay connected as a node is being dragged.  I dont want any of the charge or positioning capabilities of `force()`. Essentially I want every node to be "sticky".  Nodes will only move when being dragged.

But is there a simple way to do this?  Every example I have seen is built around a force directed graph.

I've looked at this example, http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3750558 , but it starts with a force directed graph then makes the nodes sticky. This approach seems backwards for what I want.

Is there a basic example somewhere?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

I have made a small code snippet. Hope this is helpful.

```js
var data = {
   nodes: [{
     name: "A",
     x: 200,
     y: 150
   }, {
     name: "B",
     x: 140,
     y: 300
   }, {
     name: "C",
     x: 300,
     y: 300
   }, {
     name: "D",
     x: 300,
     y: 180
   }],
   links: [{
     source: 0,
     target: 1
   }, {
     source: 1,
     target: 2
   }, {
     source: 2,
     target: 3
   }, ]
 };

 var c10 = d3.scale.category10();
 var svg = d3.select("body")
   .append("svg")
   .attr("width", 1200)
   .attr("height", 800);

 var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
   .on("drag", function(d, i) {
     d.x += d3.event.dx
     d.y += d3.event.dy
     d3.select(this).attr("cx", d.x).attr("cy", d.y);
     links.each(function(l, li) {
       if (l.source == i) {
         d3.select(this).attr("x1", d.x).attr("y1", d.y);
       } else if (l.target == i) {
         d3.select(this).attr("x2", d.x).attr("y2", d.y);
       }
     });
   });

 var links = svg.selectAll("link")
   .data(data.links)
   .enter()
   .append("line")
   .attr("class", "link")
   .attr("x1", function(l) {
     var sourceNode = data.nodes.filter(function(d, i) {
       return i == l.source
     })[0];
     d3.select(this).attr("y1", sourceNode.y);
     return sourceNode.x
   })
   .attr("x2", function(l) {
     var targetNode = data.nodes.filter(function(d, i) {
       return i == l.target
     })[0];
     d3.select(this).attr("y2", targetNode.y);
     return targetNode.x
   })
   .attr("fill", "none")
   .attr("stroke", "white");

 var nodes = svg.selectAll("node")
   .data(data.nodes)
   .enter()
   .append("circle")
   .attr("class", "node")
   .attr("cx", function(d) {
     return d.x
   })
   .attr("cy", function(d) {
     return d.y
   })
   .attr("r", 15)
   .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
     return c10(i);
   })
   .call(drag);
```

```css
svg {
    background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You are a wizard!

Comment: Will this work without manually specifying x and y coordinates and letting d3 figure it out ? (I am trying to achieve the same with large graphs and I am tying to avoid  complex graph layout algorithms)

Answer (score 5):

Gilsha has a great answer, but note that newer versions of d3 no longer use the behavior module.

Instead of this:

```
var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
   .on("drag", function(d, i) {
     d.x += d3.event.dx
     d.y += d3.event.dy
     d3.select(this).attr("cx", d.x).attr("cy", d.y);
     links.each(function(l, li) {
       if (l.source == i) {
         d3.select(this).attr("x1", d.x).attr("y1", d.y);
       } else if (l.target == i) {
         d3.select(this).attr("x2", d.x).attr("y2", d.y);
       }
     });
   });
```

Simply change d3.behavior.drag() to d3.drag()

```
var drag = d3.drag()
   .on("drag", function(d, i) {
     d.x += d3.event.dx
     d.y += d3.event.dy
     d3.select(this).attr("cx", d.x).attr("cy", d.y);
     links.each(function(l, li) {
       if (l.source == i) {
         d3.select(this).attr("x1", d.x).attr("y1", d.y);
       } else if (l.target == i) {
         d3.select(this).attr("x2", d.x).attr("y2", d.y);
       }
     });
   });
```